# public and private class in the same file

Tags: java

I created a public and private class in the same java file. It is not getting compiled.

However, if I keep a public class and a class **without** any access modifier, it is gets compiled.

What is the reason for this ?

Comment: Is the private class inside the public class?

Comment: please show the contents of this file...

Answer (score 11):

Toplevel private class is nonsense, because no other class can access this class. That is why you get compilation error..

JLS states that ;

> The access modifiers protected and
>   private pertain only to member classes
>   within a directly enclosing class
>   declaration (§8.5) and are discussed
>   in §8.5.1.

Answer (score 5):

If you try to create a .java file structured so that there are more than one public class definition or a private class definition in the root structure, as so:

```
public class SomeClass { ... }
public class SomeOtherClass { ... }
```

or

```
private class SomePrivateClass { ... }
```

there will be an error. However, you can define your private class within a public class class, like this:

```
public class SomePublicClass {
    private class SomePrivateClass { ... }
    ...
}
```

with only one base class within the java file, and this will compile.

**EDIT:** Corrected information about legal class structures based on Joachim Sauer's comment.

Comment: You **can** have more than one top-level class per `.java` file, but you **can't** have more than one `public` top-level class per `.java` file and you **can't** have a `private` top-level class *at all*.

Comment: Assuming your point would be the same if you changed both definitions to `public`, it is a style recommendation/error, not a true compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

It's illegal to specify outer classes as `private`. Without the access modifier it takes the default of only being accessible from the same package.

More info: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Access_Modifiers

Comment: This is the right answer. For people coming from C#, this is similar to C#'s behaviour of defaulting to `internal` for no access modifier, but considering an assembly instead of a package. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921365/equivalent-of-internal-in-java#:~:text=There's%20no%20equivalent%20of%20an,similar%20but%20based%20on%20package.).

Answer (score 0):

You can not declare class private unless is enclosed within another class. This is by specification, [JLS - 8.1.1 Class Modifiers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#15372)