# Equivalent of internal in java

Tags: java, access-modifiers

What is equivalent of `internal` access modifier available in C# for method in Java?

*(I know `default` i.e. methods, variables without any scope are having `package` access but I am looking for keyword equivalent)*

How can we achieve methods with `protected internal` scope in Java?

Comment: `default` , Just do `int x` instead of `public int x` or `private int x` - that way it gives access to everything in the package, but nothing outside the package.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330133/what-is-the-equivalent-of-javas-default-package-access-in-c

Comment: no-modifier means `default` but now real problem is `protected internal`

Comment: For Java peeps: [Access modifiers in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There's no equivalent of an assembly in Java, so there can't be an equivalent of an access modifier which makes a member available within an assembly.

The closest you can get to `internal` is the default accessibility which is similar but based on package.

The closest you can get to `protected internal` is `protected` (but again based on package). Note that `protected` in Java *also* gives access to the package automatically - there's nothing in Java which is as restrictive as C#'s `protected` (in terms of *only* being available within subclasses).

From [JLS 6.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2) (emphasis mine):

> A protected member or constructor of an object may be accessed **from outside the package in which it is declared** only by code that is responsible for the implementation of that object.

In other words, within the package in which it is declared, it's accessible to all code.